# How to get a list of RingCentral Contact Center Routing Numbers via API?

Tags: phone-number, ringcentral

[RingCentral has a type of phone number called Contact Center Routing Number (CCRN)](https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/Contact-Center-Routing-Number-CCRN-RingCentral-Contact-Center?language=en_US) which is used with RingCentral Office and Contact Center. Is it possible to get a list of these numbers via API?

In the Online Account Portal, these numbers are found under:

> "Phone System" > "Phone Numbers" > "Contact Center".

I looked in the [RingCentral API Reference](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference) but didn't see a section for Contact Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of Contact Center Routing Numbers (CCRNs) can be retrieved using the List Account Phone Numbers API documented here:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Phone-Numbers/listAccountPhoneNumbers

CCRN Phone Numbers will have `usageType` set to `ContactCenterNumber`.

When querying the API, the `usageType` query string parameter can be set to filter results. In the response, the same parameter is present in the phone numbers records.

The `contactCenterProvider` property is populated for CCRNs as shown below:

Here's an example:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/phone-number?usageType=ContactCenterNumber&perPage=10

HTTP 200 OK

{
  "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/phone-number?page=1&perPage=10",
  "records" : [ {
    "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/phone-number/22222222",
    "id" : 22222222,
    "phoneNumber" : "+18005550100",
    "paymentType" : "TollFree",
    "type" : "VoiceOnly",
    "usageType" : "ContactCenterNumber",
    "status" : "Normal",
    "contactCenterProvider": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "In-Contact NA"
    }
  } ]
}
```

It is possible to update the phone number's `contactCenterProvider` as shown:

```
PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/phone-number/22222222

{
  "usageType": "ContactCenterNumber",
  "contactCenterProvider": {
    "id": "3"
  }
}
```

Update Response:

```
{
  "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/phone-number/22222222",
  "id" : 22222222,
  "phoneNumber" : "+18005550100",
  "paymentType" : "TollFree",
  "type" : "VoiceOnly",
  "usageType" : "ContactCenterNumber",  
  "status" : "Normal",
  "contactCenterProvider": {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "In-Contact APAC"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Grokify's answer above, these are the `contactCenterProvider` IDs:

```
1 = In-Contact NA
2 = In-Contact EU
3 = In-Contact APAC
4 = In-Contact AUS
```